# Getting Repeater By String in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bunch of repeaters in an aspx page like "repeater1","repeater2", etc

I want to access them like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
   // get the repeater like FindRepeater("repeater"+i) and bind it
```

In the code behind Page_Load I tried

```
Repeater repeater = (Repeater)this.FindControl("repeater"+i)
```

but it says I can't cast a Control to a Repeater.

How can this be done?

Comment: I don't have an answer, that should work.  But i find it disconserting that you are appending an int to a string.  Try String.Format("repeater{0}", i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running your same code (except converting `i` tostring()), and its building fine. You can try this..

```
Repeater repeater = this.FindControl("repeater"+i.ToString()) as Repeater;
```

Comment: That's what I said something similar in my comment.  I don't know what happens if you use string concatenation with an integer because I never do it.  I usually would String.Format("repeater{0}", i) in this case.

Comment: "repeater"+i.ToString() it is same with "repeater"+i no matter type is i, the overload will call ToString

Comment: Wow, I didn't know c# did that. Thx^^

Answer (score 0):

If your page is using master pages, then you need to use the following:

```
Repeater rptr = (Repeater)this.Master.FindControl("body").FindControl("repeater" + i);
```

where body is the ContentPlaceHolderId. Additionally, if the repeaters are within a User Control you will need to do:

```
Repeater rptr = (Repeater)this.Master.FindControl("body").FindControl("MyUserControl").FindControl("repeater" + i);
```